# Issues with threads in game

Tags: java, multithreading, tic-tac-toe

I have been trying to make a basic tic-tac-toe game with some basic multithreading, but somehow both threads gain access to the synchronized statements, which is really confusing to me.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToe extends Thread {
static  char[][] map = new char[3][3];
static char notsCrosses;
static volatile boolean gameFinish = false;


public TicTacToe(String n){
    super(n);
}
public TicTacToe(){

}
public synchronized String pickPosition(int x){

    switch (x){
        case 1: map[0][0] = notsCrosses; return "00";
        case 2: map[0][1] = notsCrosses; return "01";
        case 3: map[0][2] = notsCrosses; return "02";
        case 4: map[1][0] = notsCrosses; return "10";
        case 5: map[1][1] = notsCrosses; return "11";
        case 6: map[1][2] = notsCrosses; return "12";
        case 7: map[2][0] = notsCrosses; return "20";
        case 8: map[2][1] = notsCrosses; return "21";
        case 9: map[2][2] = notsCrosses; return "22";
    }
    return null;
}

public void run() {
    if (this.getName() == "player1") {
        notsCrosses = 'X';
    } else {
        notsCrosses = 'O';
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    synchronized (this) {
        while (!gameFinish) {
            try {
                System.out.print(this.getName() + " Enter the position (1-9): ");
                int position = input.nextInt();
                pickPosition(position);

                System.out.print("h");
                printMaze();
                int yCood = Integer.parseInt(pickPosition(position).substring(0, 1));
                int xCood = Integer.parseInt(pickPosition(position).substring(1, 2));

                if (hasWon(map, xCood, yCood)) {
                    System.out.println("You win! " + this.getName());
                    gameFinish = true;
                }

                notify();
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException i) {

            }
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<map.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<map[i].length; j++){
            map[i][j] = '-';
        }

    }
    new TicTacToe().printMaze();

    TicTacToe player1 = new TicTacToe("player1");
    TicTacToe player2 = new TicTacToe("player2");

    player1.start();
    player2.start();

}
public synchronized void printMaze(){
        for(int i=0; i<map.length; i++){
            if(i==0) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                    System.out.print("---");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for(int j=0; j<map[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("|");
                System.out.print(map[i][j]);
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println();
            for(int x=0; x<3; x++) {
                System.out.print("---");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

}


public synchronized boolean hasWon(char[][] m,int xCood, int yCood){
    if(checkRow(m,yCood) || checkColumn(m,xCood) || checkDiagonal(m,xCood,yCood)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;


}

public synchronized boolean checkRow(char[][] m,int yCood){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(map[yCood][i] != notsCrosses){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public synchronized boolean checkColumn(char[][] m,int xCood){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(map[i][xCood] != notsCrosses){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public synchronized boolean checkDiagonal(char[][] m,int xCood, int yCood){
    if(map[0][0]==notsCrosses && map[1][1]==notsCrosses && map[2][2]==notsCrosses){
            return true;
    }
    else if(map[2][0]==notsCrosses && map[1][1]==notsCrosses && map[0][2]==notsCrosses){
            return true;
    }
    return false;


}
}
```

I am using the synchronize statement in the run method, what I am trying to do is only allow one thread (player) to have access to that code at a time and check against the volatile variable "gameFinish".

Comment: Synchronized only "locks" the object that it is applied to. Since you have created 2 TicTacToe objects, they each have their own synchronized lock and can run at the same time.

Comment: Also, nowhere in your code do you keep track of which player's turn it is and have a player wait *until it's their turn*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs:

1. You have two players, each of which synchronize on themselves. That won't work. You need to synchronize on some single thing that is shared.
2. Nowhere does your code keep track of which player's turn it is. So your code has no idea when to stop waiting. It just guesses and may guess wrong.

Comment: Also worth mentioning a third TickTackToe object is used to call printMaze() but the method is synchronized.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I see what I have done wrong now.